# Source that drinking on Purim is like fasting for two weeks

Tags: shabbat, sources-mekorot, purim, fast-days, intoxication

I have seen references ([1](http://www.mpaths.com/2010/02/drinking-truth-about-mitzvahs-on-pruim.html), [2](http://zchusavos.blogspot.com/2007/02/segulas-for-taanis-esther-shabbos.html)) to a saying from the holy Rebbe of Zitoshev that

> "If a person drinks wine on Purim the way he is commanded it is the same as if he fasted twice from Shabbos to Shabbos!"

I would like to know the source of this idea and/or its location in writings of the Zitshover's works.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is made in what appears to be an addendum to the 6th letter printed at the end of Ateres Tzvi (the Zitishover's commentary on the Zohar). He makes two similar statements equating drinking on Purim to fasting for 6 days. He does not source the idea but compares it to the fasting of Mar b'rei d'Ravina (of which I am unfamiliar).

> ...וכל השותה בפורים כאילו התענה משבת לשבת...
>
> ...והשתיה בה מצוה כתענית כדאמרינן במר בריה דרבינא ונמצא גאלו התענה ששת ימים...

[image: Image of above text]

Answer (score 2):

[Sefer Segulas Yisrael 80:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34222&st=&pgnum=215&hilite=) is the source you are looking for.

Comment: thank you, can you provide the source in Zitshover's work itself or where the idea originates? this seems to just be another listing quoted in his name

Comment: This is the source that everyone points to.

Comment: I understand but I cannot mark this as correct because it doesn't really answer the question. m'stamah it can actually be found somewhere in the zitshover's writings; or perhaps someone can prove that it cannot and it therefore misattributed.

Comment: The fact that a saying of the Zitshover isn't found in his writtings doesn't mean it is "misattributed"...a saying is a saying and can be transmitted and recorded in other ways.

Comment: If you read the Sefer it says Mekubal Mpi = word of mouth